# Woocommerce Hide/Remove shipping fields in My Account page

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, hook-woocommerce

I am working on ***my account page***, "adresses" (User Profile). 
I would like to *****hide or remove** some fields*** in the *"shipping address"* like: `shipping_city` and `shipping_postcode`. I have been looking for several hooks, but none of them work.
You can see the form I have now by [clicking here](https://imgur.com/zgWDfHi).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend two plugins:

1. Real-Time Find and Replace
   With this plugin, you can use Inspect in your browser (I recommend Firefox developer) and find the code for the element you desire and then replace it with a blank statement.

2)Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) for WooCommerce
This works for standard checkout fields for woocommerce.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have the second option working, but it only works for checkout, it doesn't work for this form. I'll give a try to option and let you know.